# Getting strange error when call NetSuite web service

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, crm, netsuite

I have IFRAME application defined for SSO over OAuth within NetSuite - SuiteSignOn.
OAuth process finished successfully. I got oauth token.
When call first methods in NetSuite (such as get opportunity) with bearer in authorizaiton header I got really strange error :

> USER_ERROR
>   You have a web browser version that we do not support.
> To use the system, you will first need to http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/default.htm>upgrade your web browser software.partners-java10002.bos.netledger.com

- I am using Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m for this test case
  On NetSuite supported web browsers page is written that Google Chrome 35.x is supported.

(https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=7375407&c=NLCORP&h=a66f026635e85ddaf43a&_xt=.pdf)

Value that I provided for authorization header :

> OAuth oauth_token="token", oauth_consumer_key="key", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_signature="secret", oauth_timestamp="1406638355", oauth_nonce="1406638355"

What I am doing wrong ?

The most important is that all of this was working before NetSuite 2014 release.

I am using also support for getting NetSuite's data center awareness web service url.

Comment: I am working on same, you said " I have IFRAME application defined for SSO over OAuth within NetSuite - SuiteSignOn" do you have code for the same, from where can get the code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this is to set webRequest.Headers["User-Agent"] to null when calling NetSuite SOAP API.